# Choosing word in column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

all.I need to choose some words from the text. For example, there is information: https://in.indeed.com/cmp/Ericsson/reviews?start=1720 in the column, but I just need a name of the company which is after cmp/ and before /reviews( you can see on picture) but there is a lot of different company names, therefore, I cannot search for a fixed name. Could you please help me with that? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: `url.value_counts()["https://in.indeed.com/cmp/Ericsson/reviews?start=1720"]`

Comment: you can use regex to extract the words (?<=cmp\/)(.*)(?=\/)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u have a list of strings in this format "...cmp/aaaaaaa/reviews...." u can do smth like this:

```
data = ["cmp/aaaaaaa/reviews",
        "cmp/bbbbb/reviews",
        "cmp/cccc/reviews",
        "cmp/dddd/reviews"]
for line in data:
    company_name = str(line).split("cmp/")[1].split("/reviews")[0]
    print(company_name)
```

output:

```
aaaaaaa
bbbbb
cccc
dddd
```